# Lua how to keep the start and end of a string removing the middle

Tags: lua

So I have a string the contents can be dynamic as follows and I am struggling to find a way to remove the middle but keep everything at the start and the end.

String contents (list since it is dynamic and changes allot but specific elements and order of string is always the same):

```
/media/123-remove_this/keepthis
/media/1234.REMOVEME/keepthis
/media/12345azREMOVEME/keepthis
```

Output I want :

```
/media/123/keepthis
/media/1234/keepthis
/media/12345/keepthis
```

My code :

```
local string = "/media/123remove/lalalaja"
string = string:gsub(".*media-gallery/([0-9])","")
print(string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume that every input string begins exactly with `/media/` and then some digits and ends exactly with `/` and then multiple non-slash letters, then you can just construct a pattern for the overall string, breaking it into the pieces you want to keep and the pieces you want to discard:

```
local keepBefore, discard, keepAfter = str:match "^(/media/%d+)(.*)(/[^/]+)$"
local newStr = keepBefore .. keepAfter
```

Comment: Your code does not work input:3: attempt to concatenate a nil value (local 'keepBefore')       I also have the issue that before the /media/ text anything potentialy before that i need to keep.

Comment: @C0nw0nk it works for all the examples given (it works when the stated assumptions hold). What input that you have doesn't look like the input you already explained?